# Pass an object or its values from one script to another script in Python?

Tags: python, file, class, object, import

I'm rather new to Python and especially classes/objects and the terminology. But what I want to do is: I have one object "hero". This object has a "health" variable and "inventory" list. I create the object in my main game file (called "game.py"). Then I import another file (lets say: "minigame.py"), which I want to execute.

My problem is: I would like to be able to use the "hero" object and its health variable and inventory list in the minigame script, make changes to it, and pass it back to the main game file. But when I try to import the "hero", it just creates another object of the class.

Is it possible somehow to let the scripts communicate in the way I described? To use the object and make changes to it in another script?

```
# game.py

class Hero(object):
    instruction1 = "\nYou need to set your hero's name" 
    name = ""
    health = 100
    inventory = []  

    def __init__(self): 
        self.setting()

    def setting(self):
        self.set_name()
        print('\nHi', self.name, '\n')
        self.status()

    def set_name(self):
        print(self.instruction1)
        self.name = input('')

    def status(self):
        print('Your health stat is: ', self.health) 

    def show_inventory(self): 
        print("Your current inventory contains: ", self.inventory) 

hero=Hero() 

import minigame
```

and then in my "minigame" program I tried to import the hero, but when I run the code it just creates a new one:

```
# minigame.py

print("\nminigame starts here\n")

from game import hero
```

Then I run "game.py" and the output looks like this:

You need to set your hero's name
link

Hi link

Your health stat is:  100

minigame starts here

You need to set your hero's name
zelda

Hi zelda

Your health stat is:  100

Comment: There is only one instance here, `hero`. What makes you think a new one is being created?

Comment: I just edited my question and added the output: I'm being asked for my name twice, once when "game.py" runs and then another time when "minigame.py" runs.

Comment: @eisfuechsin ***"I'm being asked for my name twice"***: Your `minigame.py` is not a valid module. Read about: [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts), obey the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part.

Comment: You've got a circular import (i.e. game imports minigame, minigame imports game), which is not good and is the reason why see hero instantiated twice. First, you should think hard if you really need two separate scripts. Do you have 2 independent games that both need the same blueprint (i.e. class) of a Hero? If you can answer yes to that, you should separate the `Hero` out into a third python file and only import this new module from the two game scripts (and not the other way around). However, this will only solve your problem of the instantiation happening twice, not your original question.